# Google DataStore - how to fetch data by ID/Name?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a query for DataStore.

I know that DataStore automatically assigns a unique "ID/Name" to each row and I wanted to fetch data from a row with a specific "ID/Name".

[image]

I'm doing the following but it's not working:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("ListOfMessages");
query.addFilter("**ID/Name**", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, message_id);
List<Entity> users = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));
for (Entity user : users) 
{
    message=(String) user.getProperty("smil_message");
}
System.out.println("message"+message);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is with `get` instead of querying:

```
datastoreService.get(KeyFactory.createKey("ListOfMessages", message_id));
```

If you must query, the property name is `__key__` and you need to filter on a fully-constructed key, not just the message_id.

```
query.addFilter("__key__", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, KeyFactory.createKey("ListOfMessages", message_id));
```

Comment: the get didn't work. So this is what I did:     Entity e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("ListOfMessages", message_id));
String mes=(String)e.getProperty("smil_message");------received error:  No entity was found matching the key: ListOfMessages("23")
System.out.println("mes"+mes);

Comment: and query.addFilter(...) didn't return anything.

Comment: It sounds like the object you're trying to get might not exist. Double-check the entity kind name and id.  Also, make sure your key is supposed to be a String and not a Long, and that the type of `message_id` matches that~

Comment: you are right. the Key is set as long. How do I change it to String. Thanks so much.

Comment: The only way to change the key is to delete this entity and store a different entity with all the same properties and a new key.  The String/longness of a key is determined when you create it with KeyFactory

Comment: Just a little comment: don't use \_\_key\_\_, but use Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY.